# Is 'honest' a suitable synonym for 'sincere'?

Tags: synonyms

Is 'honest' a suitable synonym for 'sincere'?

Comment: How about an example?

Comment: For the record, I downvoted this because I am getting a little tired of these questions. The accepted and top-voted answer more or less shows the definitions of the two words and points out that they are different. As in, you should be able to figure this out from a dictionary.

Comment: @MrHen - I agree, but in situations where the asker gives no context (like this). Perhaps those who have rep should start voting to close these as "general reference"?

Comment: @Neil: "General reference" is still relatively new and this seems to be pushing its boundaries. I feel comfortable voting down but would want to have a chat before voting to close. If I saw a few others voting I would probably join in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These are NOAD's versions of the terms:

> **sincere** |sinˈsi(ə)r|
>   adjective ( -cerer , -cerest )
>   free from pretense or deceit; proceeding from genuine feelings : *they offer their sincere thanks to Paul.*
>   • (of a person) saying what they genuinely feel or believe; not dishonest or hypocritical.
>
> **honest** |ˈänist|
>   *adjective*
>   free of deceit and untruthfulness; sincere : *I haven't been totally honest with you.*
>   • morally correct or virtuous : *I did the only right and honest thing.*
>   • [ attrib. ] fairly earned, esp. through hard work : *struggling to make an honest living.*
>   • (of an action) blameless or well intentioned even if unsuccessful or misguided : *he'd made an honest mistake*.
>   • [ attrib. ] simple, unpretentious, and unsophisticated : *good honest food with no gimmicks.*

As you see, the meanings of the two words intersect, but there are real points of difference in some of the senses. There are cases where you would not substitute one for the other. *Sincere* is hardly going to be understood to mean "simple, unpretentious, and unsophisticated" for example. And *honest* has more to do with veracity than feelings.

Comment: uhm @Robusto, I was going to write the same things, more or less. I thought nobody really hit the point, but since you kind of said what I wanted to say, you did. +1 from me. I wanna add that for this reason they can't be considered _absolute synonyms_ (for those who don't know, this is actual terminology).

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of shades of difference in the meaning. I'll just mention one that nobody has touched on so far: If you describe somebody as an *honest man,* this implies he is generally honest. If you describe somebody as being *sincere*, you are generally talking about a single instance of honesty.

For example,

> He told me that he would give me the
>   money if he found it. I thought he was sincere.

You shouldn't say *honest* here, because it's only a single instance of honesty. If you want to use the word *honest*, you should say:

> He told me that he would give me the
>   money if he found it. I thought he was being honest.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the context.

> I didn't eat the chocolate! Honest!

"Sincere" would not be a synonym in this construct.

> Tell me your honest opinion about my novel manuscript.

"Sincere" may work here, but "honest" sounds better.

> His honest contributions have brought the party to a leading position.

"Sincere" will work here, but it still sounds different from "honest".

Comment: _'Sounds better'_ is not definitive, TBH.

Comment: definitive? When is language ever definitive? There's always a component of personal experience, regional customs, localisation, etc. For some users, things sound "strange", but for others the same construct sounds "uhmm, just OK", whereas other find it "perfectly all right". This is a characteristic of a living language practiced across many continents,  that evolves and moves differently in different communities. "Definitive" is not an option to judge them, unless you are an expert in all the many regional (valid) variations of the language.

Comment: Precisely, so to rephrase: '_Sounds better'_ is rather subjective.

Comment: For me at least, these examples don't really show where the overlap and differences in meaning are.

Comment: @teylyn, @Mr.Disappointment: It's true that there is a subjective component in languages, but until a _certain point_. Beyond that point the language is pretty much definitive, otherwise there would be no rules to decide "what means what", and "how to properly say what". Just saying... Anyway I'll give my contribution.

Comment: I didn't eat the chocolate! _Honestly_ !

Comment: What I'm trying to get across is that between US, UK, AUS, SA, NZ and other places where English is one of the majority languages, there will be variations of usage. "Definitive" may apply to UK, but not to US and not to NZ. In this day and age there is no way to describe anything as "definitive" for a culture. Each culture uses their own idioms, "correct" spelling, "correct" pronunctiation. If there is such a thing as "definitive", please tell me, should I use z or s in "organization/organisation". If you now revert to "regional differences", the same thing will apply to other aspects.

Comment: While my home contains more reference works in print than most, and while I'm certainly in favor of authoritative citations when possible, I do not discount the quality of the native speaker's ear. Sometimes, the characteristic of "it sounds right" is the only answer to the some of the questions posed here. Of course, we can be somewhat more technical and observe that a given construction is "idiomatic," but that's really just the same thing.

Comment: @upthecreek: have you ever listened to the language that is actively used by teenagers? The prescriptive position would be to use "honestly", whereas the descriptive position definitely states that the current use is "like, I mean, he was like, duhh? And then I was like, Really? I didn't do it! Honest!" No teenager in their right mind would use "honestLY" in that context. This is an observation of currently used language, not a descriptive definition of how to use language correctly. Language evolves constantly. Even if we old dogs don't like where its being taken by the youngsters.

Comment: @teylyn - Well I've certainly heard teenagers use the word properly in that context, so I guess it depends on the teenager.

Comment: I wish there was an NGRAM for teenage language! I'm not disputing that some teenagers do use the adverb correctly, but from what I hear all around me every day, I note that most of them don't. UpTheCreek, good to read that all is not lost. How can we encourage the correct use of language in their less-interested peers?